# How to generate a random number within a range in substrate?

Tags: substrate

I want generate random number within a certain range. How to do that in substrate?

```
 fn draw_juror_for_citizen_profile_function(
        citizen_id: u128,
        length: usize,
    ) -> DispatchResult {

        let nonce = Self::get_and_increment_nonce();

        let random_seed = T::RandomnessSource::random(&nonce).encode();
        let random_number = u64::decode(&mut random_seed.as_ref())
        .expect("secure hashes should always be bigger than u32; qed");
        
        Ok(())
    }
```

I can't use rand package because it doesn't support no_std.

```
rng.gen_range(0..10));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `Randomness` chain extension for this. See the [Randomness docs](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/traits/traitRandomness.html).

This example shows [how to call Randomness from a contract](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/9ea95ff78dc3f22dea08f0d78e9e4c0a6f0e6b5e/examples/rand-extension/lib.rs).

There is some [discussion and another code exaxmple here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/868#issuecomment-883850608).

EDIT: **I'm not sure how random or appropriate this is** but you could build on top of your `random_seed` snippet. In your example you say you need a random number between `0` and `10` so you could do:

```
        fn max_index(array: &[u8]) -> usize {
            let mut i = 0;

            for (j, &value) in array.iter().enumerate() {
                if value > array[i] {
                    i = j;
                }
            }

            i
        }

        // generate your random seed
        let arr1 = [0; 2];
        let seed = self.env().random(&arr1).0;

        // find the maximum index for the slice [0..10]
        let rand_index = max_index(&seed.as_ref()[0..10]);
```

The returned number would be in the range `0-10`. However, this is obviously limited by the fact you're starting with a `[u8; 32]`. For larger ranges maybe you simply concatenate `u8` arrays.

Also note that this code simply takes the first max index if there are duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I know how to generate random number from seed. `let random_number = u64::decode(&mut random_seed.as_ref())` but I need random number between a range.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer that builds on your code snippet.

Comment: FYI - there is an open issue for [helper functions to generate random numbers from random seed](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/57).